# Jetpack Compose: Passing NavController into a composable function causes endless recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My app uses NavHost (actually, a NavHost within a NavHost to control a submenu), and within this second NavHost I've encountered an issue.

I pass the host's NavController as a parameter to the composable function like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NounSubScreenUI(
    navController: NavController,
    curWord: MutableState<Noun>,
    instructionsId: Int,
    getNextWord: () -> Noun,
    rightAnswerFunc: (Noun) -> String,
    getNewQuizQuestion: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
```

I do this because inside the composable, I want the phone's back button to move us up the stack, to the previous menu level:

```
    BackHandler {
        Screen.currentSubscreenSubscreenName.value = null
        navController.popBackStack()
    }
```

However, just by passing the NavController into the composable, it causes the NounSubScreenUI to be redrawn endlessly in a loop. I can confirm this by seeing a log or a breakpoint. Removing the parameter solves the issue, but then I lose the back button behavior I want.

Why is the NavController triggering endless redraws? And if I don't pass it, is there another way to get the back button functionality I want?

Comment: You should never be calling `navController.popBackStack()` in a `BackHandler` (that will break the [Predictive Back Gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture) once NavHost starts supporting it), so that isn't the right thing to do either (nor is multiple nested NavHosts what you should be doing either), but neither of those things cause endless redraws - that is due to something else in your `NounSubScreenUI` changing its state as part of composition which happens to only get kicked off when passed an unstable parameter like `NavController`.

Comment: If just passing in a NavController to your screen is causing a problem *even if you never access it*, then the problem is the rest of your method. Can you post that whole method? You'll want to post a different question to fix what you are doing with your nested NavHosts - include that link here in a comment if you want help on that too).

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified better. I essentially have submenus, and since the 2nd level submenu is in a different file (composable), I have to use NavHost again to get the NavGraphBuilder content I need to make the composable() calls, don't I? I only call rememberNavController() to get a ref once, and pass it down as the navController param to each NavHost. Is that still an issue? Won't the NavHosts share the NavHostController in that case?

Comment: No, that all sounds wrong. You can only have a single NavHost for a single NavController...

Comment: If I may ask, how am I supposed to handle a submenu then that is split across two different composable? Menu A is in composable A, and selecting something leads to menu B, which is in a separate composable and therefore needs a separate NavHost composable element for menu B. NavHost takes a navController param, which I pass down through the tree of composables, passing the same one into both NavHosts.  If this isn't the right way, how do people normally split menus between different composables? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Menu, that's a very overloaded term. That's why I suggested you ask a separate question with the details on what problem you are trying to solve, your current attempted solution using multiple NavHosts so that you can get help with how to do whatever it is you are trying to do.